# How should I go about redesigning this graphic?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, logo, minimalistic

**Update:** Scroll to the bottom for a before-and-after.

I'm designing something for my school in Photoshop, and our mascot is a knight. This is the current design:

[image: Las Lomas Knights]

Yeah, I know. It's in desperate need of a redesign. I want to do flat design, but I'm just starting out with it so I'm still trying to learn the tricks. So, how should I go about turning that into a flat and minimal graphic? (If you don't know what flat graphic design is, [here's an article on it](http://www.creativebloq.com/graphic-design/what-flat-design-3132112).

To make a long story short, I'm trying to turn a complex flat design with complicated shapes and lines into a simple, minimal "Bootstrap Style" graphic with simpler shapes and lines.

**Before         |           After (Version Two)**

[image: Before] [image: After]

Comment: Why do you feel it's not flat now? Seems pretty flat to me.

Comment: @Scott I should probably rephrase this. The whole idea behind flat design is that it's minimal, and this isn't very minimal. Some people refer to it as "Bootstrap Style"

Comment: I get that :) It is pretty flat though. If you want to make it more minimal, you simply start removing detail. Continue removing detail until you feel the overall image start loosing clarity, then stop.

Comment: You simplify to an outline, and keep only the visor and the plumage as defining shapes.

Comment: @RandomO'Reilly Okay, so what I'm doing is I'm starting with the visor using the pen tool to make a sort of triangle shape. Then I'm going to make the head, and the neck, play around with soft shadows, etc.

Comment: This is reading more like a specific request to help with a specific project. Not *really* on topic here. Things need to be a bit more general and valid for any future users. Perhaps edit a bit more?

Comment: For starters, don't use photoshop. Use a vector tool like Illustrator or Inkscape or...even better...pen and tracing paper. That way you can iterate quickly until you are happy. As for 'how' to actually draw it, there's no one 'trick'. It just takes practice and an ability to figure out which details are important and which are not.

Comment: @dubstaphone Bootstrap refers to a webdesign framework. Its completely irrelevant in the context of what you're doing. Then as DA01 mentioned its better to use Illustrator or Inkscape for digital tools on this type of project. Beyond that you have two options as far as Questions on here goes: 1. Create something and then seek a critique -- http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/672/guidelines-for-critique-questions --- or work on until you get stuck and then ask us a specific question about the part you get stuck on.

Comment: @Ryan I know that bootstrap is for the web. That's just what some people refer to it as.

Comment: @dubstaphone who exactly refers to it as? Do you have a few references where you saw this?

Comment: @dubstaphone based on your first attempt I suggest you look up some tutorials on using the pen tool. Mastering it will take you very, very far.

Comment: Yea, I can't say I've ever heard it referred to 'bootstrap style' either. But I'm old. I don't get the slang of the young'uns anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main point of any minimal design is to use the least possible shapes, paths, etc. to convey the message/image.

For something like an icon or profile, start broad and work inward. Create the basic shapes, then add definition where needed. You have a decent start already with the based shapes, although minimal doesn't have to mean strictly angular, rounding is okay. :)

You could feasibly pull off that image with one color and 3, maybe 4, shapes - the plume, the head, the visor, and possible the ridge on the top of the head.

If it were me... I'd grab a sheet of vellum paper, place it over the image, then start tracing/drawing the shapes I think I need. Keeping in mind I want the least amount of lines as possible.

[image]

Comment: I took your advice and I came up with this
http://imgur.com/gfbwvut
It's still a WIP, but it'll get there.
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Is there a reason why you want a very flat look to this logo? Because to be honest, I don't see the value that an extremely flat look is going to bring to this. School tends to have heritage and history, both of which is traditionally reflected by a style that is a little more ornate than the contemporary web UI look. I think you lose something in the "simplifying" of shape than you gain. If I were you, I would try to limit how I'd go about simplifying the logo. Try with a more minimal revamp. Remove details that don't contribute. Keep details that doesn't detach the concept from a rich past.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I would do this in vector, and I would simplify to a barebone line drawing. Then you have a basis to build on, to alter and to play with. It is by far the most sustainable place to start: strip down as much as possible, then add carefully.

Here is sort of where I would start. The strongest shapes are the visor and the plumage. Everything else is basically not needed.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

For a minimalistic design you can go for line drawing (like the below one) and then use some **monotone coloring**. It'll do great for a logo.
[image]

Comment: This image is quite far from minimalist

Comment: I said line drawing (like the below one). Just an idea for line drawing. Drawing a minimalistic figure is upto   @dubstaphone.

Comment: I hope you don't mind by I edited your answer slightly. I think you meant 'monotone' rather than 'monotonous'.

Comment: Yeah sure. Cheers!